# Am I looking at multithreading the wrong way? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

For the past few weeks now I've been studying Concurrency(Multithreading) in Java. I find it difficult and rather different than anything I've encountered in the Java language so far(or in programming in general). Often I have to reread and reread over and over again until I start to understand a small concept fully.

It's frustrating and I've wondered why this part of the Java programming language has given me so much trouble.

Usually when I look at the code of a single-threaded program I look at the main method and start going step by step in my mind through the whole execution(like a debugger). Throughout this process I try to keep in mind EVERYTHING like variables and their states(values) at every point in the execution. Often times when doing that I even stop at certain points and think how the program execution would alter in different scenarios. If I can go through a program from start to finish like that, I feel like I've fully understood the code and the material.

The problem that I have, I suppose, is that when I try to apply this method for a concurrent application, there are so much things happening at once(sleep(), synchronized methods, acquiring intrinsic locks, guarded blocks using wait(), etc.) and there's so much uncertainty of when something will execute, that it becomes nearly impossible for me to keep up with everything. That's what frustrates me, because I want to have a feeling of "I have control over what's happening", but with concurrency that's impossible.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: I guess that  [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is better place for such questions.

Comment: Got it, I'll keep that in mind in the future!

Comment: Don't try to keep in mind everything that happens, but look at the states your different parts of the application on how they respond by switching from one state to another in response to "events" (method calls more precisely). Once you manage to do that (even for single threaded applications), not only that you'll manage to see each "module" of application in interaction with the other (perceive the architecture of your app) but understanding multithreading will be a piece of cake - nothing different from single threaded, except for some points when synchronisation is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Concurrency is a simple concept, really - you have several separate paths of execution, which can interact with each other. The stuff you mentioned, like syncing, blocks, waits and so on are technical details, tools.

I would suggest trying to do some coding :-) Come up with a multi-thread program idea and code it. At some point you will need to use one of the tools you listed and it will all begin to fall into place. This is NOT a concept you should to understand only in theory ^^

Comment: mmm... Not really, concurrency is actually complicated. And synchronisations cannot be dismissed as "technical tools". Atomicity, memory ordering and locks **are** what concurrent programming is (and to fully understand some of them you even need to know what an Out Of Oder and/or non-cache-choerent CPU does internally). Plus you always have to remember that every instruction is interleaved (even in parts) with potentially another agent and the program state must deal with that. Concurrency is not simply multiple execution flows.

Comment: Well again, those are technical details you will never use in production environment. This is like saying that programming in Java is complicated, because you have to understand how the bytecode is handled and so on. It is not, those are deep-level technical details which ARE significant, but only if you need to do some magic. In modern approach, focused on code quality, simplicity and with a library or two to do the more complicated stuff for you, there is no need to go deep into the cogs. And OP stated they want to understand and use the concept, not know all technical details of it :-)

Answer (score 1):

More over a Science, Concurrent Programming is an art.

Before going into Java concurrency, PLEASE DO go through the conceptual things first.. i.e. what are the major problems in concurrency? what is a lock? what is a semaphore? what is a barrier? why we are using those? how can we use them for different purpose like variable protection, synchronization etc.? Likewise there are some.

Then you would probably get some very important knowledge before getting into language specific usage.

For a person who have followed sequential programming all the time and first looking at concurrency, definitely it would be harder to understand those things at once. But I am sure you can go to the level that you are in sequential programming for concurrent programming also after some time. :))